# SQL query - Return 0 for the column if no record found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will like to see the specific fields returns with 0 value when there is no record found.
Below are my SQL queries that I have tried so far.

```
SELECT Customer, Address, Number of lines, Date 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Date = '30-5-2022' AND Customer IN (A, B, C)
```

What it returns is only 1 row as below.

| Customer | Address | Number of Lines | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | RF | 30-5-2022 |

But what I expected to see is:

| Customer | Address | Number of Lines | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | UK | 33 | 30-5-2022 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 30-5-2022 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 30-5-2022 |

The customer B and C has no record on 30-5-2022 but I will still need to see the rows but certain columns can be 0.
Please advise if anything that I have missed out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a really weird requirement, since the Address type and the number of lines type are changing from number to nvarchar and from nvarchar to number. Is your question missing some details? (Maybe an aggregate of some sort?)

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Comment: @Marco This is user's requirement, they want to see both 3 customers in the table, if no record then return 0 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT A.Customer, ISNULL(B.Address, 0), 
ISNULL(B.[Number of lines],0), ISNULL(B.Date, '30-05-2022') Date
FROM
(
 SELECT DISTINCT Customer 
 FROM table_name
) A
LEFT JOIN table_name B
ON A.Customer = B.Customer
AND B.Date = '30-5-2022'
```

This will output all the customers present in the table. You can filter the customers with `WHERE` clause in the end of the above query based on your requirement.

[dbfiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cdbca64d473dcd9cdd6d5d86678e04b9)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming customers are in one table (cust) and other stuff in another table (table_name) and they are connected with an id called custid, you need some sweet, sweet left join action, such as:

```
SELECT c.Customer, c.Address, isnull([Number of lines],0), d.Date 
FROM cust c left join  table_name d on c.custid = d.custid and 
d.Date = '30-5-2022' where 
c.Customer IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Comment: You need to enclosed the column name in `[ ]` when it contains spaces

Comment: @Programnik I'm sry it's not working, the row for Customer B and C are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to  put A, B, C in a table and left-join the main table to it. All other conditions must then go in the `ON` clause not the `WHERE`.

You can use a virtual `VALUES` clause for this

```sql
SELECT Customer, Address, Number of lines, Date 
FROM (VALUES
 ('A'),
 ('B'),
 ('C')
) v(Customer)
LEFT JOIN table_name tn ON tn.Customer = v.Customer
                        AND tn.Date = '30-5-2022';
```

Alternatively you can pass in a Table Valued Parameter, or use a table variable. Don't forget to add a primary key.

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Customer varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @tmp(Customer) VALUES
 ('A'),
 ('B'),
 ('C');

SELECT Customer, Address, Number of lines, Date 
FROM @tmp v
LEFT JOIN table_name tn ON tn.Customer = v.Customer
                        AND tn.Date = '30-5-2022';
```